# How to add dependency of another project in github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, release

I am new to github actions, I have added release github action to one of my repos, but there is a dependency repo. I want to release first the dependency repo then the main repo. Is it possible to do this in github actions? I have checked [this](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-build-chain-cross-repo-builds#usage-example), Based on that I have added this job:

```
jobs:
  build-chain:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Run build-chain"
        id: build-chain
        uses: kiegroup/github-action-build-chain@v2.5
        with:
          definition-file: https://github.com/LakshmiRavali/twilio-cli-core/blob/main/.github/workflows/build.yml
```

but it's giving error `Error:   Cannot read property 'head' of undefined`

Comment: Looks you have to use raw file: like https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LakshmiRavali/twilio-cli-core/main/.github/workflows/build.yml

Comment: Still the same issue.